# How to get object coordinates of multilabel threshold image

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scikit-image

I use cellpose to segment my image and now want to extract object coordinates from the labels. When looking at the returned image with `image.shape` I get `[img_length, img_width, 4]`. I am not quite sure if this is a CMYK image.

The exact question I am looking to answer is how can i extract the pixel coordinates of one cell (so only 1 coloured blob) from the image below?

[image]

Comment: Can you share the original image? And also share how the multilabel file looks like?

Comment: Hi thank you, I have edited my question and attached the original image file.

Comment: The image could be PNG with the fourth channel being the alpha channel. Don't discard but analyse it and see whether it has the mask

Comment: To find coordinates of each blob, convert the image to binary and find contours. Each contour would represent an individual blob. By masking each contour you can get the coordinates

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I have tried this approach but the downside of this is that two connecting blobs will be labelled as one despite them being separated in colour.

Comment: If you could add how you color coded individual blobs to the question, it would be helpful. I should be able to reproduce your problem at my end to suggest something. Thank you

Comment: Hi Jeru, thank you I managed to solve it. To me it is not exactly clear how the masks are generated. As best as I can tell the function here is responsible for generating the masks.

https://github.com/MouseLand/cellpose/blob/e6d7d2e73fe27754288de1fb30ea71bf295930e9/cellpose/utils.py#L325

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I managed to solve it.

I iterate over every pixel in the image and save the colour.
I then use np.unique to find each unique colour value.

I remove the mask containing the background

Then I iterate over each colour and produce a binary mask for each unique colour in the image and save it to the list of cells.

```
color_array = np.empty((0, 4)) # 4 because I have four colour dimensions

        for x, y, *c in image[:, :, :]:
            color_array = np.append(color_array, c, axis = 0)

        unique_colours = np.unique(color_array, axis = 0).tolist()
        
        # Unique colours includes the background colour
        # I manually remove this colour from the list
        backg = [68,1,84,255] # This is the bg color given to cellpose images
        new_unique_colours = []

        for col in unique_colours:
            if col != backg:
                new_unique_colours.append(col)

        list_of_cells = []

        # Here I iterate through each colour to produce a binary mask of image for that colour

        for colour in new_unique_colours:
            single_cell = np.all(image == colour, axis=-1)
            list_of_cells.append(single_cell)
```